# Recursive count in JS what happen after reaching 0?

Tags: javascript, recursion, countdown

Unfortunately despite reading what I have found on line I still do not understand how it works.

here is the code :

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}

console.log(countup(5)); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

The easy part I understand is the one calling the function with n-1 until it reach 0 and then it push [] to the countArray const.

But then I do understand how it had 1 then 2, then 3 etc. to the countArray const as n = 0 and then nothing should happend because the function is not called anymore.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: When you reach 0 , countArray is set to be `array` then you push one and return  `countArray` witch is `[0,1]` and the you push 2 ... etc

Comment: But how can I push two ? you mean by myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are not getting the hang of function calls, before diving into recursion, you have to first absolutely understand the following program. I have added comments with full flow as well. Here we are calling one function from another. Recursion is also same but the same function getting called by itself. So first understand the below :-

```js
function function1(a,b)
{
let result1 = function2(a,b);
return result1 + a + b;
}

function function2(a,b){
let result2 = function3(a,b);
return result2 * a * b;
}

function function3(a,b){
let result3 = function4(a,b);
return result3 - a - b;
}

function function4(a,b){return a/b}



console.log(function1(4,2))

// It will work like this :-
/*
function1 gets called with a=2,b=4

function2 gets called with a=2,b=4

function3 gets called with a=2,b=4

function4 gets called with a=2,b=4 and doesn't call anymore function inside. Evaluates a/b = 4/2 = 2 and returns 2 back to point inside function3 where it was called

Now function 3 evaluates 2 - 2 - 4 = -4 and returns -4 back to point inside function 2 where it was called

Now function 2 evaluates -4 * 2 * 4 = -32 and returns -32 back to point inside function 1 where it was called

Now function 1 evaluates -32 + 2 + 4  = -26 and returns -26 back to point where it was called which was inside console.log

*/
```

Let's go bottom-up approach (when we reach base case of returning empty array) :-

**for `n=0`**

An empty array `[]` gets returned to the `countArray` where `n` was 1.

So **for `n=1`**, `[].push(1)` happens and now this array is returned to the `countArray` where `n` was 2.

So **for n=2**, `[1].push(2)` happens and now this array is returned to the `countArray` where `n` was 3.

This goes on till `n=5` when it all started and also this is where you are logging the final result.

The crux is that all this happend while backtracking from `n=0` to `n=5` and not from top to down.

Following is the visualization (Starts with going top to bottom and then bottom to top) :-

[image]

Comment: Ok, it is crazy I can't make any relation in my mind. I do not understand why when we push 1 the function in called with 2. I can't understand the mechanism inside. Once we pushed 1 the function should stop isn"t it ?

Comment: @MohamedNecib I have tried explaining the process via a flow chart. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: No it's ok I understood that, but how he goes back ? how he can go back. I mean when we push the empty array the n is equal to 0. So as we have a return for the called function countup we can go the next line of code which is countArray.push(n). But to me it should push 0 and not 1. And once he push Zero the code is over there are no more call to any function. How come it goes to n = 1 then n =2 etc.

Comment: So consider a very simple scenario where you're invoking a function sum to calculate sum of two numbers. Now after you have invoked that function, where does the control go ? It goes within that function right ? And then you compute the result and that you return back to the same place where function was called. So its a journey to go inside function body, do some stuff there and return back to place of function call.

Comment: Here also you are going inside each function body but only at the last condition of n = 0 the last function body got fully evaluated and now you can finally return from there. Now function with (n=1) will complete it's rest of the logic and return. Then function with (n=2) will complete it's rest of the logic and return.

Comment: What do you mean by "where does the control go" ? and by "you return back to the same place" ?

Comment: Hey @MohamedNecib I have added a program to this answer. You have to understand what's happening there otherwise you cannot understand recursion. You need to grasp how function call happens and the control goes from calling function to the called one and back again when it' s execution is complete. That's the basic of a function call.

Comment: I found something. The information that was missing was the fact that when there is no return it goes back to the previous function. Something like that. Am I right ?