# I don't understand how this recursion is working in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function countdown(n) {
    if (n < 1) {
      return [];
    } else {
      const arr = countdown(n - 1);
      arr.unshift(n);
      return arr;
    }
  }
console.log(countdown(10));
```

Now I debugged this using vs code and it showed me that at the starting when n=10 the only line which gets executed was the "arr = countdown(n - 1);" line and then it was stored in the call stack and as the n eventually became 0 the function returned [] but instead of exiting the if else loop it  ran the arr.shift(n) for n from 1 to 10 and then returned the array. I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Your question actually explained what is happening pretty well. I think perhaps you are missing that the function calls are sort of wrapped like layers of an onion. So the innermost call (n=0) has 10 calls wrapped around it, when they start returning the onion unwraps and the outer function calls each continue in turn (to the next line).

Comment: I think the following Q/A might help you to understand recursion better and you can apply the same concept here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225803/recursive-count-in-js-what-happen-after-reaching-0/66225953#66225953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me understand recursions for the first time was to literally inline function calls. Replace function calls with the function body.

To make this a bit simpler we'll add a dirty little helper and streamline countdown a bit.

```
Array.prototype.prepend = function(...args){
  this.unshift(...args);
  return this;
}

// so can write countdown() as:

function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return countdown(n - 1).prepend(n);
  }
}

// or even shorter:
function countdown(n) {
  return (n < 1) ? [] : countdown(n - 1).prepend(n);
}
// this version is easy to inline!
```

So, at this point we haven't changed anything in the logic of the code, we just moved the `unshift` part into a new method, that we defined to make our life easier.

Now let's inline the recursion:

Start with `const result = countdown(5);`, inline countdown(5) and we get `const result = (5 < 1 ? [] : countdown(5 - 1).prepend(5));`

... inline countdown(5 - 1):

```
const result = (5 < 1 ? [] :
  (4 < 1 ? [] :
    countdown(4 - 1).prepend(4)
  ).prepend(5));
```

... inline countdown(4 - 1):

```
const result = (5 < 1 ? [] :
  (4 < 1 ? [] :
    (3 < 1 ? [] :
      countdown(3 - 1).prepend(3)
    ).prepend(4)
  ).prepend(5));
```

and so on, all the way down to this:

```
const result = (5 < 1 ? [] :
  (4 < 1 ? [] :
    (3 < 1 ? [] :
      (2 < 1 ? [] :
        (1 < 1 ? [] :
          (
            // here the else-block won't be called, so nothing to add anymore. 
            // The recursion is terminated
            0 < 1 ? [] : countdown(0 - 1).prepend(0) 
            // now it's going back up:
          ).prepend(1)
        ).prepend(2)
      ).prepend(3)
    ).prepend(4)
  ).prepend(5));
```

Does this make it visible, how/why the recursion is first drilling down to `n==0` and  `return []` and after that walking back up and prepending/unshifting all the numbers.

Comment: Oh now I finally understand. Damn that's a good way to understand this. So from what i understand the function firstly gets all the values recursively and adds it to the stack recursively then it adds the value to the array then returns it.